# Cycles procedural material displacement is different (up/down) on different faces

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I've been creating a procedural material (white a bit glossy paint with rusty dents). I've created most of it without problems, but when I connect output of *noise* node (after few modifications) to *displacement* socket of material output, some of the dents are correct (downwards) and some of them are upwards. Is there a way to force it to be directed always in the opposite side of normal? (Make it always go downwards into the face)

Comment: Do you mean invert it? Or make it always go upwards?

Comment: Make it always go downwards into the face

Comment: It should be indenting in the same direction consistently, is it possible your normals are inconsistent?

Comment: @gandalf3 it isn't really possible, though it does indent always in same directiono, but not taking face normal into account

Comment: @madziorek15 Could you upload an image of what it looks like? I'm not sure I get what you mean. Also, are you using cycles experimental true displacement or just the default bump mapping?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a color ramp and set the black value to a grey to add a plateau:
[image]

Node setup:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I can read your title with this much detail, if the displacement is different on different faces, then it sounds like your normals are not all facing the same direction. You can fix this by looking in the Mesh menu (in edit mode). Select all the faces, go to Mesh->Normals-> Recalculate Outside

This will attempt to flip any normals that are facing INTO the mesh, so that they face OUT of the mesh. FYI, this doesn't work very well on non-manifold meshes.